# Is it to use last modified to figure out if file is ready for transfer?

Tags: windows, file, go

I am writing a windows service in Go, which is going to scan a directory periodically to upload files in it to our data lake.

It is a fairly simple task, but the first version had a quirk in it. Some of the files are quite large, so sometimes it takes a while for them to actually transfer into the folder (done by different service, not written by me).

My service deletes files after they are uploaded, so when it scans the directory, all files in it are to be uploaded.

So I have come up with a solution, where we before uploading the file, make sure that it has not been modified in the last 5 minutes.

Is this a safe way to make sure we don't upload and delete partial files, or could there be situations where a file is being transferred, and the last modified attribute of the file is not changed while the transfer is going on?

For 99% of the files, the transfer will never take more than 5 minutes, so theoretically it will not be a problem, I am just wondering how this works. I would assume that the last modified attribute is updated continually as the file is being written to, right?

The service calls this scan function, which returns the files to be uploaded. Does there seem to be any pitfalls here?

```
func scan() ([]os.FileInfo, error) {
    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(dir)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    var filteredFiles []os.FileInfo
    for _, file := range files {
        if file.ModTime().Before(time.Now().Add(-5*time.Minute)) {
            filteredFiles = append(filteredFiles, file)
        }
    }
    return filteredFiles, nil
}
```

Comment: This is still unreliable. Ideally, you would get the transfer service to change their behavior to "write file to temporary name, rename when finished" and your program would ignore temporary files.

Comment: What @Marc said. If it's impossible to make the service use sensible approach, try looking whether Windows FS monitoring allows to wait for an event "file opened for writing was closed" (`inotify` of Linux has this in the form of the `CLOSE_WRITE` event type). This is still imperfect but if the uploading service does not support partial transfers / transfer resuming you might count on the fact if a file was opened for writing and then closed it's done with.

Comment: If you use the temporary file approach (you should!), make sure to create the temporary file in the same filesystem as the destination, otherwise the rename is not atomic and you haven't solved the problem.